# How to update with returning values in TypeORM?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I wanted to update values and to return specified columns with PostgreSQL.

So far, what I found was update the value then use `findOne`, but then again it will always use two queries to achieve what I want.

Another is using RAW SQL, `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ... RETURNING *` and this seems a great solution so is there a way to achieve this with TypeORM using `UpdateQueryBuilder`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `createQueryBuilder`:

```
const firstUser = await connection
    .getRepository(User)
    .createQueryBuilder("user")
    .update<User>(User, {firstName: 'new first name'})
    .where("user.id = :id", { id: 1 })
    .returning(['id', 'email'])
    .updateEntity(true)
    .execute();
```

Notice: there are many ways in type orm to use [createQueryBuilder](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md) such as: `BaseEntity`, `Repository`, `EntityManager`.

Comment: Thanks. Now the prolem is mapping the `UpdateResult` to like User entity. I used `.createQueryBuilder("user").create(firstUser.raw)[0]` to get back the entity. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: You can extend the entity's class with `BaseEntity` (link below) and implement it this way: 
`User.create(updateResult.raw[0])`

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/active-record-data-mapper.md

Answer (score 5):

If using repository, this is slightly modified answer and inspired from Noam's answer:

```js
import {
  EntityRepository,
  Repository,
} from "typeorm";
import { User } from "../entities/user";

@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  
  // ... other functions

  updateUser = async (payload: User, id: string): Promise<User> => {
   const updatedData = await this.createQueryBuilder("user")
      .update<User>(User, { ...payload })
      .where("user.id = :id", { id: id })
      .returning("*") // returns all the column values
      .updateEntity(true)
      .execute();
    return updatedData.raw[0];
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired on the others answers I would like to bring a similar approach because you can have conflicts between your entity's properties and the declared column names on database, for example if the database column is declared as snake_case and the entity's using camelCase.

```js
async updateFirstName(entity: YourEntity) {
        await YourEntity.createQueryBuilder()
            .update(entity)
            .set({ firstName: 'newFirstName' })
            .whereEntity(entity)
            .returning('*')
            .execute();

        return entity;
}
```

The returned variable "entity" will contain the updated column and parsed as YourEntity definition and not as raw data if you get from the `raw[0]`.